# Reorder local commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

I want to reorder git commits at my local branch, currently, my brach looks like this.

x-x-x-x-x-x-x-0-1-2-3

now I want to change the order to below

x-x-x-x-x-x-x-0-2-1-3
how is it possible to do with git?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use an interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

This will bring up an editor looking something like the following:

```
pick 39vm3ie commit 0
pick md93ndj commit 1
pick 25sf3kd commit 2
pick 03kdoj3 commit 3
```

Note that the last four commits appear in order from *oldest* at the top, to *newest* at the bottom.  Since you want to change the order of the 1 and 2 commits, you may rearrange them as follows:

```
pick 39vm3ie commit 0
pick 25sf3kd commit 2
pick md93ndj commit 1
pick 03kdoj3 commit 3
```

Now just save the editor and close, which will initiate the rebase.  You may have to resolve some merge conflicts along the way, as rebasing rewrites history.  Note that because you are rewriting history, this option should probably be avoided on public branches which may already be checked out by other developer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `git rebase -i 0` (0 being the revision ID of 0 from your example), there you can reorder the way the revisions will be applied, but if you *really* want to be in control, you can do it like this (suppose the branch is called A and is pointing to 3):

```
git checkout A~3
git cherry-pick A~1
git cherry-pick A~2
git cherry-pick A
```

If you like the result:

```
git branch -f A # point A where we are standing right now
git checkout A
```

And that's it.